# Why data returned by a function pointer in C++ expiring and can't access all elements of array?

Tags: c++, arrays, function-pointers

When I compile below , only first "cout" works correctly.

```
void * functionname()
{
int i[3]={1,2,3};
int *p = i;
return p;
}

int main()
{

int *p = new int[3];
p= (int *)functionname();

std::cout<<p[1]<<"\n";
std::cout<<p[1]<<"\n";
std::cout<<p[2]<<"\n";
std::cout<<p[2]<<"\n";
std::cout<<p[3]<<"\n";
std::cout<<p[3]<<"\n";
delete [] p;
return 0;
}
```

would you please say what is the problem?

Comment: On a side note, an array of size 3 has the valid indexes 0, 1 and 2. You seem to think the valid indexes are 1, 2 and 3. That is not the case. 3 is an illegal index into an array of size 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
void * functionname() {
    int *i = new int[3];
    i[0] = 1;
    i[1] = 2;
    i[2] = 3;
    return i;
}
```

If the array is to exist past the end of the function, it must be put on the heap instead of the stack.

As @juanchopanza and @Servé point out, for correct memory management, make sure dispose this when you are done.

```
int *a = (int *)functionname();
//do something with a
delete[] a;
```

Comment: @user2982229 note that this is a very fragile idiom. The caller must call `delete []` on the returned pointer at some stage. At the very lest, it has to be well documented. Bit it will invariably go wrong eventually.

Comment: dont forget to delete[] the returned pointer though: int *p = functionname(); delete[] p;

Comment: Thanks, but why in my original code the first cout works correctlly, after one time usage it goes destroy??

Comment: Because `i` was on the stack, the memory was deleted after the end of the function. What was at that point after that is undefined behavior.  Read up on memory allocation in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza, if you intend to return an array of data from a thread, this is the simple, idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 3):

The array `i` is local to the function. It dies when the function returns, leaving you with a dangling pointer. Better return an `std::array`.

```
std::array<int, 3> functionname()
{
  return std::array<int, 3>{{1,2,3}};
}
```

This way, the caller gets a copy of the array and there is no problem. Before you start worrying about the cost of copying, note that usually the compiler will elide the copy, so only one array is created.

If you need access to the underlying data block, you can use either `theArray.data()` or `&theArray[0]`. These give you a pointer to the first element.

**Note 1**: If you don't have C++11 support, you can use `std::tr1::array` from the `<tr1/array>` header. If you don't have that, look at `boost::array`, or roll out your own array class.

**Note 2**: If you want an array whose size is only known at runtime, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Thank you,
The problem is that i want to use this function as a thread function and only void * acceptable.
what should I do?

Comment: @user2982229 I would use a modern threading library that doesn't need `void*`. If you can't, you can get the array's data, see my edit.

Comment: Using `theArray.data()` does *not* solve the problem. If you try to return that pointer, the `std::array` will be deleted and the memory that pointer points to will be deleted.

Comment: @PaulDraper the idea is not to return the pointer, obviously. It is to return the array, as stated. The "problem" itself is not specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You return pointer to temporary object that gets destroyed on function exit.

This will work:

```
void * functionname()
{
  static int i[3]={1,2,3};
  int *p = i;
  return p;
}
```

Note 'static' there.

Comment: But doesn't this make `i` global? (i.e. multiple calls to `functionname` may cause unexpected behavior)

Comment: Thank You, Answer @Paul Draper was grate, i dont want to use static. All the way Thnak you, :-*

Answer (score 0):

Below you find a version to get the local array to the outside. This version is close to what you have. You pass a pointer to the field you want to fill to `functionname`. You are responsible for that the copied array fits into the available space.

But, nowdays it is better to use objects like `std::vector` for stuff like that. The new move-constructor (c++11) would make it even more efficient.

Note also that you had wrong index access. C++-arrays are indexed starting at 0 and not at 1.

```
#include <iostream>

void functionname(int* p)
{
    int i[3]={1,2,3};
    std::copy(i,i+sizeof(i)/sizeof(i[0]),p);
}

int main()
{

    int *p = new int[3];
    functionname(p);

    std::cout<<p[0]<<"\n";
    std::cout<<p[1]<<"\n";
    std::cout<<p[2]<<"\n";
    delete [] p;
    return 0;
}
```